# Firefox freezes frequently

Tags: firefox

Good day,

The application Firefox freezes very frequently and I have to use 'force quit" to get out and hence I lose all my activities and it is extremely frustrating.

Only in one occasion, there was a pop-out message saying that this problem was going to be tracked but in all other occasions there is no tracking and no message
I posted this error on Ubuntu community and it was stopped and I was told to post it on launchpad.

I did try to do so with no success as after reading pages and pages which i really do not understand who would read them and why so many ridiculous and tedious rules and information, i even could not find the place or the way to post this bug.  And I thought of this ASkUBUNTU and so i am posting here in the hope for some useful help and I have to mention I am new to Linux.

Just a few minutes ago, I opened the Firefox through the Terminal and it crashed very quickly and there are some error messages and i copy and paste them hoping they can help
thank you in advance and look forward to your help and solving this frustrating problem/bug and if you wish you may post it on Launchpad or do with report as you wish as long as the problem is solved.

And here the messages appearing in Terminal, after Firefox crashed:

```
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling add_icon method of Contextcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling set_homepage method of Contextcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling clear_indicator method of Indicatorcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling clear_indicator method of Indicatorcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling clear_indicator method of Indicatorcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling set_view_location method of Contextcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling set_view_window method of Contextcontext: Timeout was reached
** (firefox:4099): WARNING **: Error calling set_view_is_active method of Contextcontext: Timeout was reached
Killed
```

Comment: Hello, can you specify the version of Ubuntu and Firefox you're using?

Comment: sorry had not visited this site for some time

Comment: sorry I pressed the return.  Ubuntu 13.04; Firefox says 22.0 Firefox canonical for Ubuntu 1.0  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't tell you how to fix the issue, but I can explain how to submit a bug report to get help from skilled people. Because the problem is probably due to a combination of several factors, they need precise data from you.

There is a [very detailed procedure](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MozillaTeam/Bugs#Crashes) for bug reports that you need to follow to provide the necessary data:

- you will need a `stacktrace` to describe what Firefox was doing before the freeze. For this you will use the command line tool `gdb`.
- you will also provide information about your system's configuration (Ubuntu and Firefox version, hardware, etc.). For that you will submit the report with `apport`.

---

**How to do it?**

1. Install `gdb`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdb
   ```
2. Install some symbols for `gdb`, which will be used to format the data:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0-dbg libglib2.0-0-dbg  libx11-6-dbg libpango1.0-0-dbg libc6-dbg
   ```
3. Close Firefox and run the following in a terminal:

   ```
   firefox -g 2>&1 | tee ~/gdb.txt  
   (gdb) handle SIG33 pass nostop noprint  
   (gdb) set pagination 0  
   (gdb) run
   ```
4. Firefox will start and you can reproduce the freeze. Once Firefox has frozen, type the following commands:

   ```
   (gdb) bt full
   (gdb) thread apply all backtrace full
   (gdb) info registers
   (gdb) quit
   ```

   A file named gdb.txt in your home folder now contains all the data.
5. Now report the bug using `apport`. Press ALT+F2 and run:

   ```
   ubuntu-bug firefox
   ```

A new window or tab will open on launchpad.net, just follow the instructions to submit the bug. Don't forget to upload the gdb.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `dom.max_script_run_time` to the value 20 in "about:config". Look how you can do this right at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script.